# How do I retrieve photos from an iphone backup?

Tags: iphone, backup, photos

I have an iphone backup with screenshots I'd like to extract. They aren't on icloud/iphoto.

Is it possible to retrieve them? I no longer have the phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Software like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) is able to extract information from backup files.
There might be free alternatives, PhoneView is just the one I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try picturescue: http://picturescueapp.com/, which is a bit cheaper and works well.

OR you can just restore your backup to a friend's iphone or a new iphone if you have one. (But if you use a friend's make sure you back it up first)